# How to calculate the averages of a variable in several binary files based on classes in another binary file?

Tags: r

I have 5 binary files(raster) with the same dimensions: the first four files represent parameter 1 and the fifth file represents land cover map with 10 classes.I want to calculate the average of all the four files based on the land cover classes. So finally we will get 4 values correspond to each class.

something like:

```
    1(first class):
  first file = 0.5(average of all pixels correspond to class 1 from the land cover)
  second file = 0.4(average of all pixels correspond to class 1 from the land cover)
  third file = 0.2(average of all pixels correspond to class 1 from the land cover)
  fourth file = 0.1(average of all pixels correspond to class 1 from the land cover)

  2(second class):
first file = 0.5(average of all pixels correspond to class 2 from the land cover)
second file = 0.4(average of all pixels correspond to class 2 from the land cover)
third file = 0.2(average of all pixels correspond to class 2 from the land cover)
fourth file = 0.1(average of all pixels correspond to class 2 from the land cover
```

and so on...

I found something very similar in stackoverflow: How to calculate the averages of a variable in one       binary file based on classes in another binary file?

However this is different in a way that I have 4 files and not one file. So I need to loop that code through all my files.

all files:

1- to read one file:

```
  fre <- file("C:\\corr.bin","rb")
  sdf<- readBin(fre, numeric(), size=4,  n=1440*720, signed=TRUE)
```

2- to read the land cover file:

```
        land <- file("C:\\land cover.bin","rb")
        over<- readBin(land, integer(), size=1,  n=1440*720, signed=F)
```

3- to calculate the average using only one file:

```
    result=tapply(sdf, over, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

I tried this for all files:

```
  dir1<- list.files("C:\filesh", "*.img", full.names = TRUE)
  fre <- file("C:\\landover_from Suj1440a.bin","rb")
  sdf<- readBin(fre, integer(), size=1,  n=1440*720, signed=F)
  results<- list()
 for (.files in seq_along(dir1)){
   list1 <- readBin(dir1[.files], numeric(), size = 4, n = 1440*720, signed = TRUE)   
   list1=tapply(list1, sdf, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
   results[[length(results) + 1L]]<- list1}
```

It seems that it worked without errors.:
     to write the results (from kith answer):

```
   for (i in seq_along(results)){
  write.table(results[[i]], paste("C:\\filesh\\data", i, ".txt", sep=""))
```

I will get  4 text files  data1, data2 ,data3,......

4-I am grateful to any-help on how to write all results into one text file. I would like the output to be one text file having all the results:

```
 class            1    2    3    4   5   6  7 ...
 data1            0.2 0.5   0.2  .   .   .  . ...
 data2            0.1  0.5  0.6
 data3            .    .    .   .   .    .  . ...
 data4            .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the files you wrote:

```
for (i in seq_along(results)){
    write.table(results[[i]], "C:\\filesh\\data%03d.txt", sep="\t")
}
```

Did you mean:

```
for (i in seq_along(results)){
    write.table(results[[i]], paste("C:\\filesh\\data", i, ".txt", sep=""))
```

Comment: yes I meant this.Thanks it wrote the results from all files to separate files.I want them to be written in one text file with the format I showed in my question.